# Check if string contains substring after space

Tags: java, string

I have a command "/library" in my app. I want to check users requests:

if request contains only "/library" -> then reply with first case;

if request contains "/library Something" -> then reply with anoter case.

Valid form for second case is: /library + space + another word. How can i divide these two requests?

Now i have this option:

```
message.equals(LIBRARY_COMMAND){
   first case
   ...
}
message.startsWith(LIBRARY_COMMAND) && message.length() > LIBRARY_COMMAND.length(){
   second case
   ...
}
```

But i think it looks not good.

Comment: use split() to split that string or req then check if any other string is present or not after /library

Comment: If you use if-else  then you don't need to check length I think.

Comment: "i think it looks not good": what about it is "not good"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ifs like this.

```
   if (message.startsWith(LIBRARY_COMMAND)) {
        if (message.length() > LIBRARY_COMMAND.length()) {
            // second case
        } else {
            // first case
        }

    }
```

Comment: What if message is null...use StringUtils

Comment: This is just to show the idea. You can leave the input validation aside, don;t you agree?

Comment: You're code is assuming he/she already implemented input validation, which can't be assumed because it's not shown. In that case, it's best to code defensively

Comment: Please read the question again, read the question's code sample again. This is not a code review. Input validation is out of the scope and is irrelevant

Comment: Eh I think it should be at least mentioned. If I were to come across this and implement your solution, that comment could help. My comment above could be revised to "FYI make sure you validate message", though.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from a scalability point of view a possible solution that includes easy scalability could be as follows:

String[] args = StringUtils.split(LIBRARY_COMMAND, " ");

Next you want to

1. check for null, if it is null, prompt the user and end proccess
2. check for # of arguments, if it's less than 1 prompt the user and end process
3. See if the first argument is "library" and if it is, execute the process
4. In that process you want to itterate through each argument and then code for each case accordingly. This proccess class should implement a interface which can be re-used for any additional commands that are added in the future.